# Retrieving empty list in the output instead of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following code, I want to filter out those values which are less than the threshold value and store it in a variable. But the below code gives an empty list in the output.

```
current_memory_available=29.373699550744604
total_memory=614480960
lst= {0: 602112, 1: 12852224, 2: 12992768, 3: 3211264, 4: 6717952, 5: 7012864, 6: 1605632, 7: 4391936, 8: 5571584, 9: 5571584, 10: 802816, 11: 6326272, 12: 11044864, 13: 11044864, 14: 401408, 15: 9840640, 16: 9840640, 17: 9840640, 18: 100352, 19: 100352, 20: 411074560, 21: 67141632, 22: 16392000}


passed = {key: (value/total_memory) * 100 for key,value in lst.items() if value < 
current_memory_available}
print(passed)
```

Thanks, Help is highly appreciated

Comment: Don't you think there are no values less than 29 in your dic?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question, He is trying to save the value using comprehension, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
current_memory_available = 29.373699550744604
total_memory=614480960
dct = {0: 602112, 1: 12852224, 2: 12992768, 3: 3211264, 4: 6717952, 5: 7012864, 6: 1605632, 7: 4391936, 8: 5571584, 9: 5571584, 10: 802816, 11: 6326272, 12: 11044864, 13: 11044864, 14: 401408, 15: 9840640, 16: 9840640, 17: 9840640, 18: 100352, 19: 100352, 20: 411074560, 21: 67141632, 22: 16392000}
new_dct = {}
for key, value in dct.items():
    calc = (value / total_memory) *100
    if calc < current_memory_available:
        new_dct[key] = value
print(new_dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

'if' statement used in dict comprehension will never get True as all the values are greater than 'current_memory_available' variable. Thus the dictionary is getting printed as null.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic is incorrect:

```
passed = {key: (value/total_memory) * 100 for key,value in lst.items() if value < 
current_memory_available}
```

Try using below:

```
passed = {key for key,value in lst.items() if (value/total_memory) * 100 < current_memory_available}
```

Full code:

```
current_memory_available=29.373699550744604
total_memory=614480960
lst= {0: 602112, 1: 12852224, 2: 12992768, 3: 3211264, 4: 6717952, 5: 7012864, 6: 1605632, 7: 4391936, 8: 5571584, 9: 5571584, 10: 802816, 11: 6326272, 12: 11044864, 13: 11044864, 14: 401408, 15: 9840640, 16: 9840640, 17: 9840640, 18: 100352, 19: 100352, 20: 411074560, 21: 67141632, 22: 16392000}


passed = {key for key,value in lst.items() if (value/total_memory) * 100 < current_memory_available}
print(passed)
```